# Rank of a leading principal submatrix of a full rank matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, matrix-analysis

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a **full rank** matrix. Let $B_k \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ be the leading principal submatrix of $A$ formed by taking the first $k$ rows and the first $k$ columns of $A$.

What can we say about the rank of $B_k$, for $k = 1, \cdots, n$? Is it true that $B_k$ is of full rank for all $k = 1, \cdots, n$? My intuition tells me this should be true, as, otherwise, $A$ would not be of full rank.

Comment: The answer to this is no. As an example, consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0}.
$$
$A$ has full rank, but none of the leading principal submatrices (besides $A$ itself) have full rank. In fact, it is possible to have zero leading-principal submatrices in an invertible matrix $A$:
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0}.
$$

Comment: Something that we **can** say is that $\operatorname{rank}(B_k) \geq n - 2k$ (or if $A$ does not have full rank, $\operatorname{rank}(B_k) \geq \operatorname{rank}(A) - 2k$). As you can see for $k=2,3$ for the second example I give above, this bound is tight in at least some cases

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context for this question? What made you ask it? It is common to consider the principal submatrices of a symmetric matrix, but is unusual to see principal submatrices considered in a more general context.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: could you elaborate a little bit on the topic of principal submatrices of symmetric matrices? I would like to show that all principal submatrices of a certain (orthonormal) matrix I'm considering are full rank, and I'm looking for some references that could possibly help me with this.

Comment: @gen I'm not sure how one would relate to the other; orthonormal matrices are not typically symmetric. In any case, perhaps you should consider posting a question about this

Comment: I forgot to mention, @BenGrossmann, the matrix I am considering is symmetric as well. That is why I was wondering if you could point to some references on this.

Comment: @gen Are you saying that it is both orthogonal and symmetric? Are you looking at Householder matrices?

Comment: @BenGrossmann: I am not sure... I never heard of them before. I looked up their Wikipedia article, while I think it's unlikely the matrix I'm looking at belongs to this class, it does seem to share a lot of the properties listed on the wiki article: it's real symmetric, orthonormal, an involution, and the eigenvalues are $\pm 1$. Are these properties sufficient for saying something interesting about the principal submatrices?

Comment: @gen Depends on what you mean by "interesting". The Cauchy interlacing theorem guarantees that if $A$ has repeating eigenvalues of sufficient multiplicity, then the principal submatrix will have those same eigenvalues.